# Schengen visa application: How to mention multiple purposes?

Tags: schengen, europe

I'm applying for a Schengen visa in Sweden for two weeks for business purposes (the company will be paying for flights, hotels, and meals for that time). I'm also planning to visit nearby countries for another two weeks, and will be covering for the expenses myself. What should I fill in the following columns:

> Purpose(s) of travel

(Can mention both business and travel or just business but explain in the next line?)

> Cost of traveling and living during the applicant’s stay is covered:

(Should I check both boxes for personal and sponsor?)

Comment: You should apply for schengen visa at place you will be staying at the longest. That's the only thing, otherwise its fine

Comment: @trystwithfreedom, you should apply for the Schengen visa from the country which is the most important, so in case of partly business and partly pleasure, almost certainly the country where you have the business meetings.

Comment: @trystwithfreedom the actual requirement is that the visa application be handled according to the "main destination" of the visit.  The duration of stay is significant, but, as Willeke notes, it is not necessarily determinative by itself.  The [code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) says "the Member State whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length of stay, counted in days, or the purpose of stay."

Comment: It's very common for people on business travel to also do a bit of tourism, so you might not need to mention a day sightseeing. If you spent a very long time there without saying you were also touring, they might be suspicious that you were there to work (not allowed) rather than just attend meetings (OK). You need to consider the impression you'll give, but generally telling the truth is the best policy.

Comment: "business and travel" cannot be the purpose of travel.  Perhaps you meant "business and tourism"

Answer (score 2):

> (Can mention both business and travel or just business but explain in the next line?)

The form asks for "purpose(s)" of travel.  The parenthetical "s" means that there may be one or more purposes.  Therefore, if you have more than one purpose, you should select all applicable items.  For transparency and to avoid confusion, write a brief explanation for the next item, which asks for "additional information on purpose of stay."

> (Should I check both boxes for personal and sponsor?)

I would.  The form has multiple opportunities to add free-form information, indicated with the words "please specify."  You can indicate, wherever makes the most sense, which costs are being borne by the sponsor and which by you.

The most important thing is to be clear and straightforward.  If you're unsure about something, imagine yourself in the position of the officer reading your application form, and imagine what the clearest way might be to give the officer the necessary information to reach the conclusion that you meet the criteria for the visa.